# jfrog rt dl <> doesn't download the file specified

Tags: ubuntu, jfrog

This is the command which I am trying to use to download a zip file from artifactory.

```
./jfrog rt dl https://ubit-artifactory-ba.xxxx.com/artifactory/my_repo/example.zip
```

I have the URL, server ID, username and password already set.

This is my log file.

```
  1 [Debug] Sending HTTP GET request to: https://ubit-artifactory-*****/artifactory/api/system/version
  2 [Info] Searching items to download...
  3 [Debug] Searching Artifactory using AQL query:
  4  items.find({"repo": "https:","path": {"$ne": "."},"$or": [{"$and":[{"path": {"$match": "/ubit-artifactory-ba.intel.com/artifacto    ry/owr-repos/Submissions/csme/14.0.20.7206_ww23.2_20.18"},"name": {"$match": "CSME-14.0.20.7206-CML.json"}}]}]}).include("name","    repo","path","actual_md5","actual_sha1","size","type","property")
  5 [Debug] Sending HTTP POST request to: https://ubit-artifactory****/artifactory/api/search/aql
  6 [Debug] The Artifactory version is: 5.3.0
  7 [Debug] Expected Artifactory version 6.9.0 or above, got 5.3.0
  8 [Debug] Artifactory response:  200 OK
  9 [Debug] Downloaded 0 artifacts.
```

This is my config file:

```
Server ID: CSME
Url: https://ubit-artifactory-ba.xxxx.com/artifactory/
User: abcd
Password: ***
Default:  true
```

Comment: "Expected Artifactory version 6.9.0 or above, got 5.3.0" The artifactory specified does not contain the version you are asking for ...

Comment: @DavidPostill: I agree. But how do I have a backward compatible jfrog cli which is compatible for Artifactory version 5.3.0? I don't have authority to update artifactory.

Comment: So speak to the person who does - your  IT department?

Comment: Isn't there a way to use jfrog cli which is compatible with artifactory 5.3.0?

Comment: I've no idea ...

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question:

The download path must be specified as the rest of the path other than the URL in config.

For example in the above instance:

The URL specified in the config is https://ubit-artifactory-ba.xxxx.com/artifactory/ and download path specified is https://ubit-artifactory-ba.xxxx.com/artifactory/my_repo/example.zip.

But the download path must be my_repo/example.zip.

This should work.